# return x doesn't work for second function

Tags: javascript, browser

Ok so I don't know how to phrase out this question, so if you have recommendations for visibility I'm glad for tips.
So now onto my problem, I'm trying to run this script I wrote in Tampermonkey but he won't return the correct answer which should be figured out in the first function.
As far as I can see, the console doesn't return an error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
My code currently looks like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron mobile-no-padding-question").addEventListener("load", auswerten());

function question() {
  var question = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-padding-question");
  var x = 0;
  var questions = ["x", "y", "z"];
  while (x < 3) {
    if (question == questions[x]) {
      return x;
      break;
    } else {
      x++;

    }
  }
}

function answer() {
  var answers = ["x", "y", "z"];
  var x = question();
  window.alert(answers[x]);
  document.getElementById(answers[x]).checked = true;
  document.getElementById("next-question").click();
}

function main() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    answer();
  }
}
```

I have never coded in Javascript before so I'm not aware of any advanced technics. Everything used was researched on the go and kinda built together. If anyone knows another approach I'd be glad to try out.

Comment: Well for starters, your `addEventListener` should have `auswerten`, *not* `auswerten()`.

Comment: What do you mean "return x doesnt work"? what is the expected output? Is anything be output? have you tried using the debugger in chrome dev console to debug your code?

Comment: And more importantly, you are comparing `question`, which is a NodeList (`getElementsByClassName()`), with `questions[x]`, which is a string. They can never be equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "he won't return" - what are you getting in the alert?

Comment: I doubt `document.getElementById(answers[x])` will work

Comment: Ok so I fixed the "auswerten" issue.

Comment: I'm trying to get x in the first function which should be the position of the correct answer, which I'm trying to take in the second function and then I'm trying to select the correct radio button out of the three with the correct answer as the button ID.

Comment: I've added an answer @RayJW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements and you are not accessing any specific element at the evaluation.

Here you are trying to find the question `if (question == questions[x])` but as `question` is an array is never going to work so the function never return the index of the question you are looking for.

You can update the evaluation like `if (question[x].innerHTML.trim() == questions[x])`

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to read the question. The element inspector tells me that the class name in which the question is contained is named this so I thought I can access the question like that.

What I was trying with the if (question == questions[x]) is to match the question which should be saved as "question" from the element I just accessed and then use it later to match it with the correct answer if that makes any sense. 

As I said I'm new to coding so I don't know exactly how to do everything.

Comment: Not sure if that works because I still can't access the question, because apparently, he can't recall the text which is saved in "`<h3 class="mobile-padding-question>`".
But I'm now getting an error which is called: ERROR: Execution of script 'Energy Air Game Bot' failed! document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function

Comment: I've updated the answer. have you check it out? @RayJW

Comment: Yes, I edited my if function. But my problem is still "The function getElementsByClassName return an array of elements and you are not accessing any specific element at the evaluation."

Comment: Look, here you are acceding specific text in each class `question[x].innerHTML.trim()`

Comment: Oh, I see, sry now I get it. But now I'm getting the error 'ERROR: Execution of script 'Energy Air Game Bot' failed! document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function' but I checked the syntax multiple times. It should be working now.

Comment: I can't tell you if it does honestly. I still don't know if it grabs the right text.